# Uninstall python 3.2 on mac os x 10.6.7

Tags: macos, uninstallation, python-3.2

According to the documentation from python.org, python 3.2 install on mac os requires an upgrade to tcl/tk 8.5.9 (for use of IDLE). In my haste, I have done both. Now my friend told me that python 3 is not recommended yet because only the built-ins and a few modules have been released for 3. The stable one so far is 2.7 (especially if one wants to make extensive use of a variety of modules). My machine has both 2.6.1 and 3.2 (because some OS services make use of 2.6.1 that comes as default with the OS).

**1. How do i remove 3.2 completely to avoid any compatibility issues?**

tcl/tk 8.5.9 was also installed and this is not the default. There was no verbose mode during installation, so I don't know whether it replaced the default one. If it did how bad can it be for the OS? and hence

**2. If the above is really bad, how do i downgrade to the old version of tcl/tk?**

In short, how do i bring my machine back to its original state? If anyone knows all the paths to the directories and files I can do it manually.

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since Python installs using a package manager, you can use [Suspicious Package](http://www.mothersruin.com/software/SuspiciousPackage/) to look at the install script and where everything is installed.

Be aware this is for demonstration purposes only. My environment is OSX 10.6.8 and am uninstalling python-3.2.2-macosx10.6.dmg.

```
sudo rm -Rfv /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/ /Applications/Python\ 3.2/

cd /usr/local/bin/

sudo rm -fv 2to3 2to3-3.2 idle3 idle3.2 pydoc3 pydoc3.2 python3 python3-32 python3-config python3.2 python3.2-32 python3.2-config python3.2m python3.2m-config pythonw3 pythonw3-32 pythonw3.2 pythonw3.2-32 /Developer/Documentation/Python/Reference\ Documentation\ 3.2
```

Comment: ahem, doesn't this remove all versions of python "framework"?

Comment: Note that deleting `Python.framework` will delete all user-installed versions of Python. If you want to just delete 3.2, then delete `Python.framework/Versions/3.2` only.

Answer (score 4):

I did the same (3.2 on a mac 10.6) and:
-Moved both the Python 3.2 folder and the ActiveState ActiveTcl folder from the Applications Folder to the Trash.
-Moved the Python.framework folder from the Library/Frameworks folder to the Trash.

Running System profiler shows only the 2.6 version of Python.

Marcos

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The python 3.2 install puts some files in '/usr/local/bin'. Does dropping folders you mentioned into trash take care of these files too?

Comment: I did the same thing as Marcos said and it works!.  
@user702200, it doesn't take care of files in /usr/local/bin but according to /dmg/readme, "It can optionally place links to the command-line tools in /usr/local/bin as well.", I think it's fine for them to be there.

Answer (score 0):

just uninstall 3x version of python if you have already installed it. Eclipse  has that option when you click "see whats already installed". 
Install later 2.7 version. It works for me on my OS X 10.9.2 with Eclipse Juno.

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question very well, and you realise this question is from 3 years ago right?